# Mac Equivalent to Windows CMD f8

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line

In Windows if I entered several commands and built up a little history, I could execute previous commands by typing a prefix at the command line and pressing `F8` [(Windows Keyboard shortcuts)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-keyboard.html) to cycle through all commands in my history matching that prefix. Is there any equivalent in MacOS?

---

By way of example If I sequentially executed these commands

```
dir .
echo IgnoreThis
dir /b %TEMP%
dir /s .
dir /b %USERPROFILE%
echo IgnoreThis
```

If I then entered

`dir /b`<kbd>F8</kbd>

I would first receive an autocompletion to

```
dir /b %TEMP%
```

and if I pressed <kbd>F8</kbd> again it would autocomplete to

```
dir /b %USERPROFILE%
```

For another example if I instead entered

`dir`<kbd>F8</kbd>

For the first, second, and third times I pressed <kbd>F8</kbd> I would get

```
dir .
dir /b %TEMP%
dir /s .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your ~/.inputrc:

```
# ↑
"\e[A":history-search-backward
# ↓
"\e[B":history-search-forward

# Try to stay at the same the cursor position when moving through the history.
set history-preserve-point on
```

The way this operation works is you first type your partial command prefix and begin pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrows to begin cycling in reverse and forward respectively through the command history matches to your typed prefix.

Comment: Also some useful options: https://gist.github.com/so-lit/c6b3661f67929fd0851ce4627e579c55

Comment: Spot on, just what I needed! I'm back in business, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that the Mac shell (called BASH, one of many Unix shells) is quite a bit more powerful than the Windows DOS/Powershell prompt.

Briefly yes but autocomplete works very differently on the Mac and follows Unix shell conventions in place long before Windows/DOS was a gleam in Bill Gates eye.

The up and down arrows will scroll backwards and forwards through the commands you have already entered. And even if you quit out of terminal all that history is remembered across sessions. Well not back to the beginning of time but BASH remembers a substantial history of commands.

You can string multiple commands together with "&&" :

```
cd /users/steve/desktop && rem picture.jpg
```

That will CD to my user profile and then delete a file called picture.jpg

Books (literally) have been written on the BASH shell and a little searching around the internet will come up with quite a lot of information on navigating, using, programming/scripting. if you don't specify the BASH shell on macOS you'll get a lot of Linux results which are generally applicable but many of the commands are different.

If you are really interested in geeking out you can change to a different shell, there are several built-in, or another terminal program that has more features than the one that comes with macOS. Finding and using said options will be left up to you in the spirit of exploration.